# MySql not exists from table array

Tags: mysql, join, compare

I am currently compiling a list of `seller_id`'s which has made an active sale within the past 12 months, my issue is SELECTING all of the `seller_id`'s from table B where it does not exist in the recent_sellers subquery...

I am getting the error:

MySQL said: Documentation
1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

```
SELECT (SELECT a.`seller_id`,a.`plan_written`
    FROM `plans` a
    WHERE a.`plan_written` > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)) AS recent_sellers
  FROM
  `plans` b
  WHERE b.seller_id != recent_sellers.seller_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM plans t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM plans t2
                   WHERE t1.seller_id = t2.seller_id
                     AND t2.plan_written > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 12 MONTH )
```